# How to trace cors request using javascript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

We have third party `js` that is referenced through cdn. We are using third party service to track user behavior. We have implemented code to call a function from that js that sends requests to a different domain. We want to trace those requests sent to different domain using javascript. How can I do it using javascript?

I have tried below code to trace requests, but it seems it only traces same domain requests.

```
var open = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open,
    send = window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

function openReplacement(method, url, async, user, password) {
    this._url = url;
    console.log('url -------- ' + url);
    return open.apply(this, arguments);
}

function sendReplacement(data) {
    debugger;
    console.log('data -------- ' + data);
    return send.apply(this, arguments);
}

window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = openReplacement;
window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = sendReplacement;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "trace those requests"? JavaScript and browsers don't provide much in the way of low-level networking information.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Meaning that we want to trace request/response headers or payload information.

Answer (score 0):

if you using jquery, it have some global ajax function:
for example:

```
    let open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
        this.addEventListener("load", event => function () {
            console.log(event.target);
            if (event.target.responseURL.indexOf('YourDomain')>-1) {
               //Do Something
            }
        }, false);
        open.apply(this, arguments);
    };
```

[source](https://riptutorial.com/javascript/example/20197/listening-to-ajax-events-at-a-global-level)

Comment: i test it and it worked, if cqrs for that domain is enabled,give it a shot

Comment: I can see requests to other domain in network tab in dev tools. But could not get in `ajaxSend` method.

Comment: i changed my answer, try this one